# Restful service with SSL

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, servlets, ssl

Hi I have created a Restful service and I have a Post method which the client calls Post method.(WCF DOT net 4.0 VS 2012)

My client told me that he wont supply any certificate to me and I need to authenticate only with my certificate only ( one way authentication thats what he says)

1. I got .pfx file from my certificate authority and installed the .pfx in IIS 7 using the import option.
2. Created a web site and make it Https 443 port and selected the imported .pfx file from the drop down
3. Select my web site and select SSL Settings and checked require SSL and checked Accept option button - on Client certificates

I did the following change in my config file to indicate this site is using SSL

```
   'security mode="Transport"
        transport clientCredentialType="None"
      security'
```

My question is

1. Did my client has to install a .cert file in his machine which is signed by my CA ?
2. If he installs that is enough or he need to use that cert file in his every request?
3. How I am sure if the someone use the someother cert file that is signed by my CA ?
4. How I can validate the certificate?
5. Is anything is missing here for SSL HTTPS communication.

Please guide me for to make a secured Restful service using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

One way authentication or simple SSL means only server authenticates yourself with X.509 certificate. Client is anonymous.

1. No. Client does not have to install certificate which is signed by your CA. Client has to trust your CA. Many CA certs are already in windows trust store. If your CA cert is not among them client has to install CA cert into Trusted Root Certification Authorities.
2. Trusting your CA cert is enough. Client will not send any certificate in any request. We will receive your SSL certificate at the beginning of your communication and validate it (check if your cert was issued by trusted CA).
3. Your SSL certificate has a reference to your site in it. Mostly `CN` of `subject` of server SSL certificate is equal to host name. So if your service is reachable on https://example.com your SSL certificate will have CN=example.com. You can check on https://www.google.com/. But there are also other options of including site reference to certificate. When client validates server SSL certificate it validates also this. CA should verify that you are the owner of the domain before it issues a SSL certificate to you.
4. I don't understand. You (on server) do not validate any certificate.
5. You can test SSL using browser. Just visit the URL of your service in browser, you should get response without any warning if your service supports also GET request.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response and it really helpful, For point No. 4 If the client is anonymous I want to make sure only certain people can approach me for service ( I want to know who is sending the request to me ) I want to authenticate the client and send response ( so using certificate how can I deal this - i dont have user info in the request client) - so from the server prespective how i can find the client using certificate.

Comment: You can access client certificate in custom handler. Here is a tutorial [How to: Create a Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx). It is possible that client does not send any certificate. If you want to force client to send certificate, select **Require** in the **Client certificates** area of IIS. Then it is called mutual authentication or 2WAY authentication.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, my client will always send my certificate along with his request, to implement that I am getting the following problem (claimset count = 0) [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715309/getting-the-certificate-info-from-the-request-on-restful-post [link] better direction on this will be more helpful to me